# How to determine minimum reasonable MD timing for ligand-protein complex

Tags: molecular-dynamics, high-performance-computing, gromacs, proteins

I am working on protein-ligand complex MD simulation using GROMACS.
Now I'm running the [tutorial](http://www.mdtutorials.com/gmx/complex/08_MD.html).

```
gmx grompp -f md.mdp -c npt.gro -t npt.cpt -p topol.top -n index.ndx -o md_0_10.tpr

gmx mdrun -deffnm md_0_10
```

It use 10ns for md runs. The parameter is defined in it's [md.mdp](http://www.mdtutorials.com/gmx/complex/Files/md.mdp) file.

`nsteps                  = 5000000   ; 2 * 5000000 = 10000 ps (10 ns)`

It tooks 5 days to run with 16 cores CPU.
Is it normal?

Thus I seek a shorter time to execute.
What is the minimum reasonable time we can use? Is 1ns enough?

-Sca

Comment: I don't know any tool that can "predict" the simulation time. But can said that it will depend on many different factors as: number of atoms, timestep, number of CPUs, number of GPUs, if using more than one node, network speed, even the compilation parameters used will affect the final wall time.

Comment: What are you trying to study with this simulation? You need a rough estimate of the timescale of relevant processes before you can determine how long the MD should run. Ligand unbinding can have a rate of once per second (or slower), so MD might not be the right tool. As a reviewer, I would be very suspicious of a paper with less than 4 runs of 100 ns each (for molecular mechanics of biomolecular systems).

Comment: I gave my +1 awhile back, but have you been able to consider the comments by Camps and dwhswenson? It would be nice to see a bit of interaction with the people trying to help.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments or someone would like to provide an answer.